# How can I delete lines that are similar to another one, but shorter?

Tags: bash

Good evening! I need your help :) I have this kind of text file here

```
Espece_A ACGT
Espece_B ACCT
Espece_B GACCTT
Espece_B ATCTGG
Espece_C ACCTG
Espece_D ACCT
```

Each line contains a species name (Espece_X) and a corresponding sequence (AACGT for example), separated by a space. Lines are sorted according to their first word.

My goal is to delete the lines that are similar to another one, but shorter. I don't know how to do that!

In this example the second line should be deleted because is is exactly similar to the third one, but shorter.

RESULTING FILE :

```
Espece_A ACGT
Espece_B GACCTT
Espece_B ATCTGG
Espece_C ACCTG
Espece_D ACCT
```

Thank you very much in advance Adrien

Comment: Welcome, is there a minimum length of the sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 2x `awk`, `sort` and `cut`:

```
awk '{print length($2), NR, $0}' file |
  sort -k1,1nr |
  awk '
  {
    for(i=1;i<=cnt;i++){
      split(lines[i], tmp)
      if ($3 == tmp[3] && $1 < tmp[1] && index(tmp[4], $4)) next
    }
    lines[++cnt]=$0
  }
  END{
    for(i=1;i<=cnt;i++) print lines[i]
  }' |
  sort -k2,2n |
  cut -d' ' -f3-
```

1. `awk`: Print length of the sequence field, line number and the original line
2. `sort`: Reverse sort by length of the sequence field, the output is this:

   ```
   6 3 Espece_B GACCTT
   6 4 Espece_B ATCTGG
   5 5 Espece_C ACCTG
   4 1 Espece_A ACGT
   4 2 Espece_B ACCT
   4 6 Espece_D ACCT
   ```
3. `awk`: Add records which should not be removed to array `lines`.
   For each record loop over the already added array entries and test

   - if the species name is the same (`$3 == tmp[3]`)
   - if the sequence is shorter (`$1 < tmp[1]`)
   - if the sequence is a substring (`index(tmp[4], $4)`)

   If all three conditions are true, then skip to the `next` record, otherwise add the current record to the array. Print the array elements in the `end` block.
4. `sort`: By original line number
5. `cut`: Remove the first two fields

Answer (score 1):

A short Python program can accomplish this, and can be easily run in Bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
last_line = ""
for line in sys.stdin:
    if len(line) > len(last_line) or line[0:-1] != last_line[0:len(line)-1]:
        print(line, end='')
    last_line = line
```

**Usage:**

- copy the above code into a file named `del_shorter.py`
- make the file executable: `chmod +x del_shorter.py`
- run it with a reverse-sorted file as input, and sort the output again:

```
cat your_file.txt |sort -r |./del_short_matches.py |sort
```

Comment: Dear Bitinerant,
thank you very much for your answer.
Your solution works great, but I realized that my example is not covering every possible cases.
Here is the case where it does not work (I have added a G at the beginiing of the 3rd sequence): 

'''Espece_A ACGT
Espece_B ACCT
Espece_B GACCTT
Espece_B ATCTGG
Espece_C ACCTG
Espece_D ACCT'''

I still want the second line removed as it is the same than the third one, but shorter.

Thank you in advance! (I have edited my main post)

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not too large then here is a sledgehammer

```
while read s g; 
   do n=$(sed -nE "/"$s" .*"$g".*/p" file | wc -l); 
  [ $n -eq 1 ] && echo $s $g;  
done < file
```

Just returns matches where `species .*gene.*` are unique.